# How to use csv file with ForEach controller in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am doing teacher tool testing in JMeter. I have 30 number of entries in .csv file. I want to iterate first 10 entries through any logic controller for thread one and other 10 entries with same controller for second thread and this process should be repeated 3 number of threads. 
inside logic controller i have http sampler.

Thread Group (3)-
    csv config file-
    foreach controller(1-10)-
         http sampler-

```
repeat foreach loop controller(11-20)
```

Comment: What about `CSV Data Set Config` in `Config Elements`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I understood your question you need the following:

1. Read all values from CSV file
2. For 1st thread iterate first 10 entries
3. For 2nd thread iterate second 10 entries
4. etc.

In order to implement this you'll need the following test plan structure:

- Thread Group - to define virtual user threads, loops, ramp-up, etc.

  - Beanshell Sampler - to read CSV file into JMeter Variables
  - If Controller 1 (1st thread condition)

    - ForEach Controller 1
    - HTTP Request
  - If Controller 2 (2nd thread condition)

    - ForEach Controller 2
    - HTTP Request
  - etc.

In regards to detailed configuration

**Beanshell Sampler**

Put the following code into Beanshell Sampler Script area:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/your/file.csv"));
String line;
int counter = 1;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   vars.put("VAR_" + counter, line);
   counter++;
}
br.close();
```

The code above will read all the lines from `file.csv` and store it into JMeter Variables like:

```
VAR_1=first line of your CSV file
VAR_2=second line of your CSV file
VAR_3=....
```

**If Controller 1**

If you want anything under this controller to be applicable for 1st user only set the following condition:

```
${__threadNum}==1
```

**ForEach Controller 1**

If you want 1st thread to read first 10 lines from CSV file configure your ForEach Controller 1 as follows:

- Input variable prefix: `VAR`
- Start index for loop: `0`
- End index for loop: `10`
- Output variable name: anything meaningful, i.e. `CURRENT_VAR`

**HTTP Request 1**

Refer current line as `${CURRENT_VAR}` where required.

Hope it's clear enough.

References and how-to's :

- [Beanshell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)
- [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)
- [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)
- [__threadNum function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)

Comment: one more thing i want to know that i have suppose total 12 entries in one .csv(A) file and 3 entries in another .csv(B) file.I want to execute this case in such way that for each entry from B .csv file will take "any of 4 entries(randomly) from A.csv"                                       

scenario is like that
A.csv file
A
B
C

in B.csv file
1 to 12 entries

output should be like that
A --- any 4 entries
B---- any 4 entries
C---- any 4 entries

Comment: For file `B` you can use "classic" approach of CSV Data Set Config. For file `A` you can use __CSVRead and __Random functions combination or use above approach.

Comment: can u describe more clear in scenario? actaully doing teacher tool testing

Comment: Detailed scenario description won't fit into StackOverflow comment field. If you're uncertain regarding how to set up "classic" way of CSV Data Set Config I would suggest checking http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config guide

Answer (score 1):

Add a Loop controller to the Thread (Forever=True), then add the "CSV data set Config" as child to the Thread. Jmeter will then stop when all "CSV data set" rows are run.

Eg:

> Thread
>
> > Loop Controller
> >
> > > CSV Data Set Config
> > >       HTTP Reqeust

Jmeter version=5.

Answer (score 0):

Thread

> Loop Controller
>
> > CSV Config
> >
> > - Set Filename
> > - Set variable names
> > - Set Recycle on EOF to false
> > - Set Stop thread on EOF to true
> > - Set Sharing mode to Current Thread

> > HTTP Request